# How to show view on button click?

Tags: javascript, dynamic, dynamics-crm-2011, odata, xrm

I have Web Resource (HTML + JavaScript) which contains a button in it. I wanted to show View on click of button. Can I use OData to filter contents of **view** and show it?

To be more specific, I want to pass filter (preferably OData) to my created view, or existing view, and show it on button click. I wanted to open view of **Contact** entity.

To show the entity form I used following code, but what to use with view?

```
var parameters = {};
parameters["ContactID"] = guid;
Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm("contact", parameters);
```

Kindly suggest how to achieve in Dynamics CRM?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could dynamically build the url.  The Views are displayed on the  main.aspx page, and the query string parameters decide what is displayed.

First, [get the url of a view](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328483.aspx) to see what the url looks like, so you know what you are building.

Use Xrm.Page.getClientUrl to get the base url and build the rest of the query string using the correct parameters, like the the id of the view.

Something like this...double check the syntax and parameters from the view url in your system:

```
var baseUrl = window.parent.Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl();
var viewUrl = baseUrl + 'main.aspx?etn=myEntity&amp;viewid=%7b<GUID value of view id>%7d'
window.open(viewUrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Here how can you open a view with a proper url
>
> follow belew steps
>
> 1) Go to Settings > Customization > Customize the system
>    2) click
>   on views of contact entity
>    3) double click on the view you want to
>   open through url
>    For example : In my case I double clicked view
>   (All Active Contacts)  and got the following url in address bar

```
http://myserverName/myOrgName/tools/vieweditor/viewManager.aspx?appSolutionId=%7bFD140AAF-4DF4-11DD-BD17-0019B9312238%7d&entityId=%7b608861BC-50A4-4C5F-A02C-21FE1943E2CF%7d&id=%7bD26D3BD5-4CBE-E211-A1BD-000C2972E8B4%7d
```

> Copy the Guid from above URL
>   which is in my case : ***D26D3BD5-4CBE-E211-A1BD-000C2972E8B4***
>   Use below url to open the view

```
http://myserverName/myOrgName/main.aspx?etn=contact&pagetype=entitylist&viewid={D26D3BD5-4CBE-E211-A1BD-000C2972E8B4}&viewtype=1039&navbar=off&cmdbar=false
```

> **NOTE :** change servername,organization name and paste the ***GUID of the view*** in URL as shown above
>
> Hope this help